# Making a request to end points wrong

Tags: java, android, json

I submitted my project about fetching popular movies data in Udacity, and when i saw my review there was one thing to change, "The end points are perfectly implemented and fetches the correct result every time a request is made. But there is a small problem that instead of making a request to end point top_rated you are making a request to vote_average which makes it fetch wrong result!" But when i change to top_rated, the app doesn't fetch at all what is the problem? I don't get it, it fetches perfectly like this,And I don't see in the moviesDB nothing in JSON that says top_rated..
[ScreeenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ7qM.png)

Information about the Project>> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZlN1fUsCSKuInLECcJkslIqvpKlP7jWL2TP9m6UiA6I/pub?embedded=true

My project >> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wxYsxio2kbo44anndE9_93h13pWKTk0J

Comment: hi! i voted to close your question. sorry, i know this can be frustrating. please first find the core of your problem. as a general guideline, ask your question in a way so that it can be useful to other people in the future. see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. [This page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) explains why.

Answer (score 1):

What does your json look like thats coming back from the url.

It looks like you also never make a request to
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

based on your code and the project it seems like you need to fetch the top rated, then add it to your movie object.

in the project description look for Stage 1 - API Hints